# Open keyboard hides the toolbar below fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-videoview

I have a fragment that is put in an activity. This fragment consists of a `VideoView`and `EditText`component.
I dont have a problem showing the video or edit the text. The problem occurs when i try to edit the text. When the text is edited and i close the keyboard. The panning have removed my toolbar.
Or atleast put it behind the fragment from some reason

[image]

Anyone know why this is happening? Never seen this problem before

Comment: Hi dude,Did u get the answer for it?.How did you solve this problem?.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your manifest for your 'activity' element

Comment: This does solve the problem with the black toolbar. But it creates a new problem as well. It moves the EditText view so it overlaps the videoview. 
This could make it really hard for users to type out a text

Comment: I also faced the same problem.The keyboard is hide the bottom edit text, i could not able to see the typed text.